# Highcharts and Ajax using php

Tags: php, ajax, highcharts

Hi I am trying to reload a pie of Highcharts in this way:

```
$("#Actualizar").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax/core/Ajax_Request.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{
                    AppRequest:'Dashboard/htmlPies',
                    params: { 'params':{'orden':'orden'}}
            },
            success:function (result) {
                chart.series[0].setData(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

In the server side I have this.

```
    $resultado=array(100, 1000, 400, 200);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
```

And it is working, but what I want is to add the this.point.name like this

```
    $resultado=array('a'=>100, 'b'=>1000, 'c'=>400, 'd'=>200);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Now it does not draw anything.

The original js to fill the data is like this

```
                data: [
                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                    ['IE',       26.8],
                    ['Chrome',       12.8],
                    ['Safari',    8.5],
                    ['Opera',     6.2],
                    ['Others',   0.7]
                ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `data` in JavaScript is an array which contains lots of two item arrays.  To mimic this in PHP:

```
$resultado=array(array('a', 100), array('b', 1000), array('c', 400), array('d', 200));
```

More likely, you'll want to do this in a loop, e.g.:

```
$resultado = array();
$dataItems = array('a'=>100, 'b'=>1000, 'c'=>400, 'd'=>200);
foreach ($dataItems as $key => $value) {
    $resultado[] = array($key, $value);
}
```

There's probably a more efficient way to do this earlier in your code, and build the data structure appropriately . . .

Comment: Thanks Ernie, It works your solution. Now how do I build a better data structure?